# Como separar sequência de números em uma array

Tags: c#, array

Por exemplo, o usuário coloca em uma textarea "1234 5678 1011 1213"
Fiz um sistema que ele coloca ponto e virgula em cada espaço, agora preciso saber como faço para armazenar uma sequência de digito em uma array, para poder fazer um código que depois de 6 sequências, pule uma linha.

Por exemplo, o usuário insere assim:
1090 5411 1006 / 6061 - 4025 4587 6518 / 7892

Sistema já modifica para:
1090;5411;1006;6061;4025;4587;6518;7892

E desejo que a cada 6 sequências de números, ele pule uma linha:
1090;5411;1006;6061;4025;4587;
6518;7892

```
private void btnHSCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var hs = hs_codes.Text;
            var texto = new StringBuilder(hs.Length);
            var digito = true;

            foreach (var chr in hs)
            {
                if (char.IsDigit(chr))
                {
                    if (!digito) texto.Append(';');
                    texto.Append(chr);
                    digito = true;
                }
                else digito = false;
            }

            txt_alterado.ReadOnly = false;
            txt_alterado.Focus();

            txt_alterado.Text = texto.ToString();

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use o método estático da classe [`Regex`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.7.2)  [`Replace(String, String, String)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_String_) para fazer as substituições. O que não for dígito ele substitui por ";" e depois coloca um quebra de linha após seis sequências de dígitos terminados por ";"

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;



private void btnHSCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     txt_alterado.ReadOnly = false;
     txt_alterado.Focus();

     txt_alterado.Text = 
          Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(hs_codes.Text, @"[^\d]+", ";"), @"(\d+;){6}", "$0\n");

 }
```

Comment: Depois para separar em `String[]` use o método [String.Split(char)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_Char___) usando ';' como parâmetro. `var strarr = txt_alterado.Text.Split(';');`